# How to allow multiple blank records in access table, but no duplicates?

Tags: ms-access, vba, duplicates

I have an access check in and check out form. When a unit is checked out, a `UserID` is required. When that unit is checked back in, the `UserID` is updated to `""`. I want to prevent a `UserID` from checking out two units at once, however If I try to make the `UserID` field a unique field, it will count the blanks as duplicates and not allow it.

How can I prevent duplicated `UserID` entries ?

Answer (score 1):

Normalize the User Id by using a VBA function

```vb
Public Function NormalizeUserID(ByVal uid As Variant)
    uid = Replace(Nz(uid), " ", "")
    NormalizeUserId = LCase$(uid) 'Optional
End Function
```

This removes all the spaces and makes the user id lower case. If you only want to remove leading and trailing spaces, use `Trim` instead. This is up to you.

```vb
Public Function NormalizeUserId(ByVal uid As Variant)
    uid = Trim(uid)
    NormalizeUserId = LCase(uid)
End Function
```

Apply it when the user entered a username in the AfterUpdate event of the textbox

```vb
Private Sub txtUserId_AfterUpdate()
    me!txtUserId = NormalizeUserID(me!txtUserId)
End Sub
```

Additionally, make sure that the UserId column in the table has a unique index.

---

If you prefer to keep the user name as the user entered it, use 2 columns in the table: Maybe on called `UserIdDisplay` and one `UserIdNormalized`. In the Form you would bind the textbox to `UserIdDisplay` and change the `AfterUpdate` to

```
Private Sub txtUserIdDisplay_AfterUpdate()
    me!UserIdNormalized = NormalizeUserID(me!txtUserIdDisplay)
End Sub
```

And in the table, add a unique index to `UserIdNormalized`.

---

Note:

It is better to store the user information in a separate user table. You would create a user table with an `AutoNumber` as primary key and these 2 user id columns as text columns with a unique index as described above.

In the checkout table you would link a user through this `AutoNumber` (the checkout table will need a `Number Long` field to store the user number.

```
 tblUser                                 tblCheckout
+---------------------------------+     +==-----------------------+
| PK  UserID           AutoNumber |<-+  | PK  Id      AutoNumber  |
+---------------------------------+  |  +-------------------------+
|     UserIdDisplay    Text(20)   |  +--o FK  UserId  Number Long |
| UX  UserIdNormalized Text(20)   |     |     other columns ...   |
|     optional: username etc. ... |     +=========================+
+---------------------------------+
```

The advantages are that you have exactly one user record per user, even if this user makes several checkouts. The user can change his visible user id without affecting the internal `UserID`. You can store additional user information (name, address, e-mail etc.).

Comment: I cannot make the UserID column unique in the table because the default value is a blank entry, access is reading these as duplicate values.

Comment: You can check `Ignore Nulls` in the index properties.

Comment: I tried that and it still wont ignore the blank cells.

Comment: The cells must contain `Null`, not an empty string `""`. Set `Allow Zero Length` to `No` for this text field. This will automatically turn empty strings into `Nulls`. This is tricky, since there is no visible difference between an empty string an `Null`..

Answer (score 1):

Don't store the checkout status in the same table as the item. These are conceptually different things anyway. Create a second table, `UnitCheckout`, that has a PK of `UnitId` (or whatever your Primary key is on your Unit table). This will be a 1:1 relationship. If something is checked out it will have a record in this table with a `UnitId` and a `UserId`. If it is not checked out then there will be no record at all. This will allow you to put a unique constraint on the `UnitCheckout` table that is enforceable.